# JavaScript Split Coordinates From A String

Tags: javascript

I have an mapping app that has a search bar. When a user types in lat/lon coordinates in this format: **45.000 -122.00**, the map zooms to that point. The coordinates have to be entered into the search bar in that exact format to be able to zoom to the correct spot. I want to be able to take both coordinates from that string and use them as inputs elsewhere in my script. I've tried using parseFloat() from the resulting string, but it only grabs the first coordinate 45.000. It's stopping at the space. I could remove the space, but then I would have a string like this **45.000-122.000** I need to be able to split those chunks into two separate strings. I have to take into account that the coordinates will be five digits, and there may or may not be a leading negative sign depending on the coordinates.

Here is what I have so far:

```
search.startup();

on(search,'search-results', function(e) {
    var searchValue = e.value;
    console.log ('search results',searchValue);
    var coordinates = parseFloat(searchValue);
     console.log(coordinates);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, you need to [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) at the space and then `parseFloat` each element.

Comment: "*When a user types in lat/lon coordinates, the map zooms to that point.*" - so there already is some code that parses them?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the built-in [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to turn your string into an array with your two coordinate values. Then you can parse from there. Try this:

```
let value = '45.000 -122.000';

let array = value.split(' ');

console.log(parseFloat(array[0]), parseFloat(array[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Here's another solution I found:

```
str_1 = searchValue.split(/\s(.+)/)[0];  //everything before the first space
str_2 = searchValue.split(/\s(.+)/)[1];  //everything after the first space
                                       var latStr = parseFloat(str_1);
                                       var lonStr = parseFloat(str_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expression

```
search.startup();
on(search,'search-results', function(e) {
  var searchValue = e.value;
  var regex = /(\d+\.\d+)\s+((?:-\s*)?\d+\.\d+)/;
  var match = regex.exec(searchValue);
  console.log ('search results', searchValue);
  if (match) {
    var coordinates = [parseFloat(match[1]), parseFloat(match[2])];
    console.log(coordinates);
  }
});
```